# setting custom argv arguments size in java using eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, multithreading, arguments, argv

I have a quick question. I have a multithreaded benchmark that I need to run.
I am using Eclipse, not command line.

Inside the main java function I have this code:

`if(argv.length != 0 ) {
        nthreads = Integer.parseInt(argv[0]);
      } else {
        System.out.println("Number of threads equals to 1!");
        nthreads = 1;
      }`

How can I set 8 argv arguments that correspond to 8 threads in eclipse?
I though through Run->Run configurations but I was not able to run it properly and
`"Number of threads equals to 1!"` keeps poping up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add command line arguments via eclipse like this

**Run --> Run Configurations --> Java Application**

In this you'll a window like below where the second tab is *Arguments*. Give your command line arguments as comma separated values(I've placed a *HERE* just to highlight that box).

[image: CLA]

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer R.J 
I kind of knew that part. The real problem is that I want 8 threas to run.
So, what do you sugget to put in Program arguments?
If I put `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8` as Program arguments it will not work.
Can you help with that?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: @GeorgeKourouleas - 8? That's the no. of threads value you want to set to `nthreads` right?

Comment: Yes, that is the number of threads I want to set to nthreads.
The problem is that `Number of threads equals to 1!` keeps popping up if I put `8` in program arguments.

Comment: From the code snippet you've posted, I don't think it should happen. There has to be more to this because the current snippet should work fine.

Comment: I managed to find a solution after all. Thanks for your immediate help.